# Django - show to user an object corresponding to the current url

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

apologies for the misleading title; let's say I've got this kind of link:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
       <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'rental-create' car.pk %}">Order this car!</a>
</div>
```

which leads to a view I use to process ordering my cars

```
class RentalCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = RentalCreateForm
    template_name = 'rentals/rental_create.html'
    success_message = 'Created'
    context_object_name = 'order'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('rental-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.profile = self.request.user.profile
        car = Car.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form.instance.car = car
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

now I would like to simply use my **object (car) pk** in the template or directly in the form I've defined above.

As you can see, I've managed to access this variable in my form_valid method:

```
car = Car.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

however, this mechanism only ensures that after saving an instance to the database, the **car** would be the same as in the requested url.

My point is to use the car object (which corresponds to url like */rental/new/1/*) in the template, or as the non-editable form field.

in brief - I would like to show user the current car he is ordering.

here is my forms.py

```
class RentalCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rental
        fields = ('start_date', 'end_date', 'additional_info',)
        exclude = ('profile', 'paid')
        widgets = {
            'start_date': DateInput(),
            'end_date': DateInput()
        }
```

Does Django provide a simple way to achieve this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add extra context in the `get_context_data` method.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['car'] = get_object_or_404(Car, pk=self.kwargs['pk']
    return context
```

Note that I've used `get_object_or_404` so that you get a 404 page when the car does not exist. If you used `get()`, then a `CarDoesNotExist` exception would cause a 500 server error.

Now you can access `{{ car }}` in the template.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you.